# prompting for location authorization in iOS8

Tags: ios8, cllocationmanager

I have looked at other similar questions on this site, apple dev site and countless YouTube videos but I am still unable to figure this out. There seems to be very little info on getting a user's location in Xcode/iOS8.

I have a map view that works fine except when I click on a button to get my location, nothing happens and in the logs I see

> Trying to start MapKit location updates without prompting for location authorization. Must call `-[CLLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization]` or `-[CLLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization]` first.

I don't understand what I am doing wrong. I am very new to programming and all information I have seen doesn't make much sense to me.

I'm using storyboards in my app, and the code specific to this is as follows:

**mapViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
@interface mapViewController : UIViewController  {
MKMapView *mapview;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapview;
-(IBAction)setMap:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)getCurrentLocation:(id)sender;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@end
```

**mapViewController.m**

```
#import "mapViewController.h"
@interface mapViewController ()
@end
@implementation mapViewController {
CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}
@synthesize mapview;
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
self.locationManager.delegate=self;
self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization;
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
-(IBAction)setMap:(id)sender {
switch (((UISegmentedControl *) sender).selectedSegmentIndex) {
    case 0:
        mapview.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
        break;
    case 1:
        mapview.mapType = MKMapTypeSatellite;
        break;
    case 2:
        mapview.mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid;
        break;
       default:
        break;
}
}
-(IBAction)getCurrentLocation:(id)sender {
mapview.showsUserLocation = YES;
}
@end
```

I've been struggling with this for so long I'm tearing my hair out. Can someone point out where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is quite self-explained.

First of all, you didn't initialized `CLLocationManager` in your `viewDidLoad`. You can initialize with (before the `delegate` line):

```
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
```

Then, you have to request for location service, using `[self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization]` or `[self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization]`. (Not to forget to add corresponding usage description key in `Info.plist`).

Last, you have to check the response of authorization from user. If user denied the authorization, you shouldn't start any Location Service-related actions, until you ask again.

---

**Update** if you support iOS 7 as well, the codes will be slightly different.

Comment: Hi thanks heaps for that, I have now got it working. The other issue I have is that the button I setup to get user's location doesn't seem to work. I've got a connection to the button so when it is clicked it refers to getCurrentLocation but nothing happens. Do I have something missing?

Comment: yes, your delegates are probably not written well. However, this is a separate question, you can open a new question instead & I'll help. (Hint: tag me with @ followed by name) Last, if you find this question helpful, please upvote & accept the answer using the Up arrow and the tick icon on the left of the question.

Comment: thanks, I will open a new question, it won't let me upvote yet as I need at least 15rep, but I'll come back and do that once I reach that level

Comment: Hey Raptor, I couldn't figure out how to tag you, I have raised a new question:

http://stackoverflow.com/q/27976933/4456507

Comment: Got it. will look into it.